# Is this shloka in Brahma Vaivarta Purana?

Tags: krishna, identification-request, radha, brahma-vaivarta-purana

> “sri radha nama mantrena murcha sanmasiki bhavetnocarreta mata spastam parikshit hit krn munih“

Is this shloka in Brahma Vaivarta Puran, if YES, then please tell the shloka/addhyay?

Comment: If you can translate, please tell it in English also...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what source mentions that this particular verse is to found in the Brahmavaivarta Purana. Jîva Goswâmî had quoted from Brahmavaivarta Purâna while describing the rites related to Janmâstami. The present-version of Brahmavaivarta Purâna also contains a chapter explaining the rites of Janmâstami but out of the nearly 100 verses qouted by Jîva Goswâmî, only around 30 verses are found in the present-version.

Similarly, Raghunandana, one of the great lawmaker of Bengali Hindu society(besides Jîmûtavâhana & Kulluka Bhatta) had also also quoted extensively from Linga Purâna while framing the rules of Shâradîyâ Durgâ Pujâ in his compendium Astâvimshati Tattva' but the present-version of Linga Purâna hardly contains any glorification of Âdyâshakti, let alone mention Her worship.

This is a recurring problem when Nibandhas quote from Purânas certain verses which can't be found in present-versions. The texts which have commentaries composed upon them are free from this type of abberations. This is the reason why Bhagavadgîtâ & Devîmâhâtmya are uniform because they have numerous commentaries composed upon them.